# EditText onKeyListener only get keyCode for 1-9, why?

Tags: android, keylistener

Here's the code:

```
EditText keyboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
keyboard.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {

                Log.d("TEST", "Key Code: "+keyCode);

                return true;
            }

            return true;
        }
     });
```

But I'm only getting the key codes for the numbers, 1-9, and not with all the keys. Why? How can I handle a key event? I added this:

```
switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
        Log.d("TEST", "Key Code: "+keyCode);
        break;
   }
```

But it never get called.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) instead since "software input methods will generally not trigger the methods of" an OnKeyListener according to [setOnKeyListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener%28android.view.View.OnKeyListener%29).